# How to access Ubuntu installed as dual boot but with out leaving Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, rdp

I have Ubuntu latest version installed along side Windows 10 as dual boot. I usually program in windows for everything PHP related and boot to Ubuntu for everything ruby related. Both works perfectly. The problem is that lately, I got 2 projects to supervise as tech lead. one in PHP and one in Ruby. In order to help out my teams I constantly need to boot from Windows to Ubuntu and Ubuntu to Windows.

I know I could setup PHP on Ubuntu but the stack used by the team requires windows for various administrative task CRM and devops related as well as offiche365 for team communication and reporting.

Setting up Ruby on windows is a big no no . It's so much easier and stable under Ubuntu. Also my ruby teams policy is to use Ubuntu and nothing else so everybody has the same environment.

This situation where having both platforms needed at the same time is unusual but I just got confirmation for 2 new milestones on both project which means it will be like this for at least 6 more months . So It's time to find a better way. The back and forth is really a pain!

So I was wandering if there was a way to access my Ubuntu device from windows with out leaving windows. Like RDP from windows to Ubuntu on the same computer. Is that even possible? If so, what would be the steps to achieve this? I really need to keep Ubuntu as dual boot thought. So having this extra option to quick access with out having to reboot and loose all the work, momentum and setup I have undergoing in windows would really help me a long way.

Comment: You can't.  If you're on a true Dual Boot, then you can only run one OS at a time.  And since you're booted into Windows you can't run anything on the Ubuntu side.  Windows cannot read EXT partitions either, so you cannot access the Ubuntu data from Windows, or run things on Ubuntu from within Windows.  Ubuntu within Windows is best done in a Virtual Machine installed on the Windows side of things, and that's not an Ubuntu support issue.

Comment: There is a program to let Windows see ext(x) type partitions(at least there was), but do not know if it safe enough for your situation(might mess everything up).  On a single machine a VM is best bet to switch between the two fast.

Comment: @crip659 that program to read ext partitions hasn't worked for ages, and is suffering infinite bitrot.

Comment: @Thomas Ward thanks did hear about it years ago and was not sure if it still working.

Comment: Darn ... I was hoping somebody somewhere created something that detects the linux  drive and loads it inside a window you can set to fullscreen or something like that... Looks like a great idea thought. If anybody is looking for a project, this could be a popular one. I guess I will have to continue booting to ubuntu and windows until I get my ubuntu environment set up inside a virtual machine.